Is there a reason to make home made glucose syrup?
Every candy recipe calls for glucose syrup, but I cant find one in my area. I can make inverted syrup before cooking, but does making syrup and adding it to the sugar is the same as adding sugar (amount of sugar from recipe plus amount of syrup) + acid  without intermediate step?

It's not true that "every candy recipe calls for glucose syrup". There are lots of recipes with table sugar only. So you can simply search more intensively for other recipes.

theoretically yes, you don't need to make separate inverted syrup and make it all in one go. But keep in mind that exposure to acids could harm gelatin, glucose syrup used not only as doctoring agent but its also reduces sweetness. Where inverted sugar make food more sweet, its also have humectant (keep moist) properties which could be undesirable. Gelatin itself act as doctoring agent. Well its only a theory, I’ll write a full answer when try it hands on
